# ASP.NET MVC has File(outPdfStream, "application/pdf") returned bloating bytes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, iis

In the MVC controller function, I have the following codes:

```
                EvoPdf.PdfConverter converter = new EvoPdf.PdfConverter();
            converter.LicenseKey = "e/MyLicenceKey+uT05+X65eb67e3t7Q==";
            converter.PdfDocumentOptions.BottomMargin = margin;
            converter.PdfDocumentOptions.TopMargin = margin;
            converter.PdfDocumentOptions.LeftMargin = margin;
            converter.PdfDocumentOptions.RightMargin = margin;
            var outPdfStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            converter.SavePdfFromHtmlStreamToStream(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                , ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority), outPdfStream);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"inline; filename={reportInfo.ReportName}");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.Private);
           // System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\test\aaaa.pdf", bytes);
            return File(outPdfStream, "application/pdf");
```

Firefox could receive the PDF response and display correctly. The Adobe Reader XI plugin in IE 10 complains that "File does not begin with'%PDF'. Local\EWH([b~rkqj", and Chrome complains incorrect format. When I save the PDF through Firefox, the size of the file is around 2.6 MB, however, the commented out codes above saved pdf to aaaa.pdf with size around 400k. And the file could be open and rendered correctly in all browsers and PDF readers.

Apparently somehow ASP.NET or IIS 7.5/8 has bloat/pollute the 400KB which something else which may be tolerated by Firefox but not others. Through the VS debugger, I am pretty sure the bytes/stream is around 400 KB when the function returns, but somehow when the response leaves IIS, the response becomes a few times bigger.

I am using MVC5 and .NET 4.5, and the hosts are IIS EXpress, IIS 7.5, IIS8 on Windows 7 and Server 2012 with all latest patches.

Comment: even adding                 Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", outPdfStream.Length.ToString());
won't help, with the same inflating response.

Comment: Choose save as to save the downloaded file and open that file in a binary editor to see what are the actual contents.

Comment: yes, the 2.6 MB file is the actually content but only viewable in Firefox. Adobe Reader, IE and Chrom consider it is corrupted. The commented codes saved a file at size 400 KB, and all browsers and PDF reader could read it correctly.

Comment: I understand but we need to see what that 2.6 mb of data contains

Comment: Thank you for the hint, Oguz. According to HxD, the head part of the file is actually the HTML to be rendered. The strange thing is, if I save the stream of bytes created by the PDF converter into a file inside the controller, the file aaaa.pdf is correct. I guess the javascript reference inside the html may be causing some trouble.

Comment: This is a very common issue. You should clear the response with Response.Clear() before writing the pdf content to the response, and should call Response.End() afterwards. That would send only the pdf content to the client.

Comment: yes. I render the html inside the controller thus the response is already polluted. Please make your answer rather than comment so I could mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common issue.

You should clear the response with Response.Clear() before writing the pdf content to the response,

and then should call Response.End() afterwards.

That would send only the pdf content to the client.

Comment: the html in the return is generated during rendering html inside the controller, before rendering html to pdf.